# Python: how to reshape a Pandas dataframe and keeping the information?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe counting the geographical information of points.

```
df:   
     A   B    ax  ay   bx   by
0    x   y    5   7    3    2
1    z   w    2   0    7    4
2    k   x    5   7    2    0
3    v   y    2   3    3    2
```

I would like to create a dataframe with the geographical info of the unique points

```
df1:  
     ID   x   y
0    x    5   7
1    y    3   2
2    z    2   0
3    w    7   4
4    k    5   7
5    v    2   3
```

Answer (score 3):

First flatten values in columns by [`numpy.ravel`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html), create `DataFrame` by contructor and last add [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html), thanks @zipa:

```
a = df[['A','B']].values.ravel()
b = df[['ax','bx']].values.ravel()
c = df[['ay','by']].values.ravel()

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':a, 'x':b, 'y':c}).drop_duplicates('ID').reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
  ID  x  y
0  x  5  7
1  y  3  2
2  z  2  0
3  w  7  4
4  k  5  7
5  v  2  3
```

Comment: I believe you'll need to add `.drop_duplicates('ID').reset_index(drop=True)` to match desired output.